# Is $\sin( \theta(t))$ a function composition?

Tags: calculus

Is $\sin( \theta(t))$ actually a composition of two functions, $\sin$ and $\theta$?

And also, does it matter if I write $\sin( \theta(t))$ or $\sin \theta(t)$?

Comment: If you accept $\phi(x)=x$ is the constant function, then every function $y=f(x)$ is a composition of two functions $\phi$ and $f$.

Comment: What do you mean by writing $\sin\theta(t)$? If you mean $\sin\theta(t)=\sin(\theta(t))$, it doesn't matter. If you mean $\sin\theta(t)= \text{an apple}$ it does matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no, respectively. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $f(t)=\sin(\theta(t))$ is a composition of two function. Now, if you want to take time derivative use chain rule: $\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{df}{d\theta} \frac{d\theta}{dt}=\cos(\theta(t))\dot{\theta}(t)$.

Also, both forms $\sin(\theta(t))$ and $\sin\theta(t)$ are used. However the first left no doubts.